# como pasarle los datos del elemento actual de la lista a una funcion?

Tags: c++

Tengo este proyecto que le llevo trabajando hace unas semanas.. lo estoy trabajando con listas.. alumnos y materias.. con esta funcion inscribo un alumno previamente registrado:

```
void inscribirAlumno(Alumno_Inscrito*&listaAlumno_Inscrito,Alumno*listaAlumno,Asignatura*listaAsignatura){
int cedula,id1,i=0;
Alumno_Inscrito*nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito=new Alumno_Inscrito();
cout<<"Digite la cedula del estudiante a inscribir: ";
cin>>cedula;
bool band1=false,band2=false;

Alumno*actualAlumno=new Alumno();
actualAlumno=listaAlumno;
Alumno*aux1;
//BUSQUEDA DEL ESTUDIANTE
while((actualAlumno !=NULL)&&(actualAlumno->ci <= cedula)){
    if(actualAlumno->ci == cedula){
        band1=true;
    }
    aux1=actualAlumno;
    actualAlumno=actualAlumno->siguiente;
}

if(band1==true){
    //REGISTRO DEL ESTUDIANTE
actualAlumno=aux1;
cout<<"\nResgristrando alumno: "<<actualAlumno->nombre;
nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->nombre=actualAlumno->nombre;
nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->ci=cedula;

Alumno_Inscrito*aux2=listaAlumno_Inscrito;
Alumno_Inscrito*aux3;

while((aux2 != NULL)&&(aux2->ci < cedula)){
    aux3=aux2;
    aux2=aux2->siguiente    ;
}

if(listaAlumno_Inscrito==aux2){
    listaAlumno_Inscrito=nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito;
}

else{
    aux3->siguiente=nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito;
}

nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->siguiente=aux2;

cout<<"\nDatos del estudiante "<<nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->nombre<<" cargados correctamente"<<endl;

//REGISTRO DE MATERIAS

nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->asigT=registroAsignaturas(listaAlumno_Inscrito,listaAsignatura,i,id1,band2);

}
else{
    cout<<"Estudiante no encontrado"<<endl;
}
system("pause");    
}
```

Con esta función `nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->asigT=registroAsignaturas(listaAlumno_Inscrito,listaAsignatura,i,id1,band2);`
aparte de saber cuantas materias inscribio. me llama a otra funcion para inscribirle las materias:

```
int registroAsignaturas(Alumno_Inscrito*&nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito,Asignatura*&listaAsignatura,int i,int id1,bool band2){
char band3;
do{
Asignatura*actualAsignatura=new Asignatura();
actualAsignatura=listaAsignatura;
Asignatura*aux1;
cout<<"Materia "<<i+1<<endl;
cout<<"Indique el ID de la Asignatura a buscar: ";cin>>id1;
while((actualAsignatura !=NULL)&&(actualAsignatura->id <= id1)){
    if(actualAsignatura->id == id1){
        band2=true;
    }
    aux1=actualAsignatura;
    actualAsignatura=actualAsignatura->siguiente;
    }

    if(band2==true){
        cout<<"    "<<aux1->nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"DATOS:"<<endl;
        cout<<"ID.: "<<aux1->id;
        cout<<"\nEstudiantes: ["<<aux1->alumT<<"]";
        cout<<endl<<endl;
        nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->asig[i].nombre=aux1->nombre;
        nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->asig[i].id=aux1->id;
        aux1->alum[aux1->alumT].nombre=nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->nombre;
        cout<<"\nnombre: "<<nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->nombre;
        cout<<"\nMateria "<<nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->asig[i].nombre<<" agegada correctamente ";
        cout<<"a estudiante "<<aux1->alum[aux1->alumT].nombre;
        aux1->alumT++;
        i++;
        cout<<"\nRegistar la Asignatura: "<<i+1<<"?(s/n) ";
        cin>>band3;

    }
    else{
        cout<<"Asignatura no encontrado"<<endl;
    }
    }while((band3=='s')||(band3=='S')||(i==7));
return i;
}
```

El problema lo tengo en estas líneas de codigo:

```
if(band2==true){
    cout<<"    "<<aux1->nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"DATOS:"<<endl;
    cout<<"ID.: "<<aux1->id;
    cout<<"\nEstudiantes: ["<<aux1->alumT<<"]";
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->asig[i].nombre=aux1->nombre;
    nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->asig[i].id=aux1->id;
    aux1->alum[aux1->alumT].nombre=nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->nombre;
    cout<<"\nnombre: "<<nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->nombre;
    cout<<"\nMateria "<<nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->asig[i].nombre<<" agegada correctamente ";
    cout<<"a estudiante "<<aux1->alum[aux1->alumT].nombre;
    aux1->alumT++;
    i++;
    cout<<"\nRegistar la Asignatura: "<<i+1<<"?(s/n) ";
    cin>>band3;
```

Si el primer elemento de la lista es al que se le asignan las materias.. luego si se la quiero asignar a otro elemento de la lista siempre se le asignan al primero.. pero si asigno primero las materias al segundo elemento luego al asignarselo al primero se asignan correctamente.. por ejemplo.. si yo registro los alumnos juan y pedro.. y a la hora de inscribirlos busco a juan en esta linea `cout<<"\nDatos del estudiante "<<nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->nombre<<" cargados correctamente"<<endl;` me arroja el nombre de Juan.. y luego en la otra funcion en esta linea `cout<<"\nnombre: "<<nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->nombre;`me dice juan.. pero si luego de registrar a juan.. registro a pedro.. al buscarlo en esta linea `cout<<"\nDatos del estudiante "<<nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->nombre<<" cargados correctamente"<<endl;`sale pedro.. pero en esta linea de la otra funcion `cout<<"\nnombre: "<<nuevo_Alumno_Inscrito->nombre;` me sale juan.. y los datos se guardan en Juan y no en Pedro..

Nota: Acabo de probar que uniendo la segunda funcion en la primera si trabaja bien... pero a mi no me gusta trabajar asi con tanto codigo en una sola función... de momento lo dejare asi.. pero si me pueden orientar a pasar los parametros correctamente a la segunda funcion seria de mucha utilidad

Answer (score 0):

Tu código, además de ser complicado de seguir, tiene múltiples fallos. Para empezar estás confundiendo listas con punteros, y **no es lo mismo**, fíjate en tu función `inscribirAlumno`:

```
void inscribirAlumno(Alumno_Inscrito*&listaAlumno_Inscrito,Alumno*listaAlumno,Asignatura*listaAsignatura)
```

Recibes tres parámetros que además de ser inconsistentes en el tipo (el primero es referencia  puntero y los dos siguientes punteros) son inconsistentes en su nomenclatura pues los llamas `lista` cuando en realidad no son una lista. Esa confusión se ha visto varias veces en esta comunidad, [consulta este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/169454/2742) para más detalles.

Esta confusión lista-puntero empuja a desarrollar con punteros en crudo, lo cuál es propenso a errores, hace el código más complicado de seguir y mantener, complica la implementación y para colmo... si quieres usar listas: no reinventes la rueda, ya existen listas en la librería estándar.

#### No he podido ver tu error pero...

En `inscribirAlumno` reservas memoria para después ignorar la memoria solicitada, creando así una fuga de meomria:

```
// Pedir memoria para un 'Alumno'
Alumno*actualAlumno=new Alumno();
// Sobrescribir el puntero recién creado con el puntero recibido como argumento de la función.
actualAlumno=listaAlumno;
```

Tienes el mismo fallo en `registroAsignaturas`:

```
// Pedir memoria para un 'Asignatura'
Asignatura*actualAsignatura=new Asignatura();
// Sobrescribir el puntero recién creado con el puntero recibido como argumento de la función.
actualAsignatura=listaAsignatura;
```

Además tienes un caos de punteros auxiliares, es muy difícil estar seguro de dónde estás apuntando en cada momento, más aún cuando los nombres de tus punteros y variables no son auto-explicativos y debes repasar continuamente el código para intentar entender su objetivo.

Mi consejo es que rehagas todo el código de manera más simple, dices que *no te gusta trabajar así con tanto código en una sola función* ¡perfecto! estás más cerca de alcanzar el [principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica), ahora llévalo más allá y crea funciones de búsqueda, impresión y alta de elementos, eso podría simplificar mucho tu código; seguramente con eso entenderás mejor tu propio código y resolverás el problema.

Por desgracia, no te puedo ayudar mejor.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder.. en general el proyecto hace lo que quiero.. alamcena estudiantes, materias y profesores.. las relaciona(de una manera muy simple, pero por ahora me importa eso, mas tarde quisiera aprender mas sobre multilistas para relacionar varias estructuras osea relacion muchos a muchos).. no sabria como hacerlo mas simple.. esa fue la forma que me ensenaron a trabajar con lista en la universidad.. mi problema era ue al pasarle los parametros a la funcion registrar asignaturas no se pasaban bien los datos del alumno buscado sino siempre el primero de la lista

Comment: Una pregunta: ¿Es necesario que trabajes con tu propia lista o puedes usar estructuras ya creadas como `std::list`?