# Violación de segmento punteros C

Tags: c, punteros

tengo un problema con "violación de segmento" en el código de más abajo. Más preciso es, cuando el código llega a la parte del `if(comparacion_estacion()){}` me da error en cierta iteración del `while`, cuando la lista llega a cierto string `"US Universidad de Santiago"` (la lista tiene almacenado las estaciones de metro: [Abreviacion] [Nombre estacion]).
La función `comparacion_estacion` sí sirve, osea, sí me retorna `true` (primera iteración) y `false` (siguientes) pero no se cual será el detalle que hace dejar el código a mitad.

Anexo:
si comento toda la parte del `if comparacion_estacion(lista->nombre,combinaciones[i].inicio)){}`, funciona bien el `for` y el `while`, osea, me recorre el `struct` y la lista,

```
Nodo *conectar_linea(Nodo *lista){
 Nodo *aux;
 aux = lista;
   for(int i=0;i<22;i++){
    while(lista != NULL){

        if(comparacion_estaciones(lista->nombre,combinaciones[i].inicio)){
            cout<<"entro al if"<<endl;

           if(comparacion_estaciones(combinaciones[i].linea_termino,"linea1 ")){

                lista=conectar_estacion(lista,linea1,combinaciones[i].inicio,combinaciones[i].termino);
            }

            if(comparacion_estaciones(combinaciones[i].linea_termino,"Linea2 ")){}

            if(comparacion_linea(combinaciones[i].linea_termino,"Linea5 ")){
                cout<<"Exito"<<endl;
            }else
                cout<<"No son iguales";

            if(comparacion_estaciones(combinaciones[i].linea_termino,"Linea4 ")){}

            if(comparacion_estaciones(combinaciones[i].linea_termino,"Linea4a ")){}

            if(comparacion_estaciones(combinaciones[i].linea_termino,"Linea6 ")){}

        }

        else{
            puts("No se pudo conectar estaciones");
        }
        cout<<lista->nombre<<endl;
      lista=lista->sig;
      cout<<lista->nombre<<endl;
    }
    lista = aux;
}
return lista;
}
```

Adjunto también función `comparacion_estaciones`

```
    bool comparacion_estaciones(string estacion1, string estacion2 ){ 
       char modificar1[5], modificar2[4];
       char *token1, *token2;
strcpy(modificar1,estacion1.c_str());strcpy(modificar2,estacion2.c_str()); 
token1 = strtok(modificar1," ");token2 = strtok(modificar2," ");

  if(*token1 == *token2) {

    return true;}
else{
    return false;
}
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa

```
     ./programa 
    entro al if
    Exito
    SP San Pablo
    NP Neptuno
    No se pudo conectar estaciones
    NP Neptuno
    PJ Pajaritos
    No se pudo conectar estaciones
    PJ Pajaritos
    LR Las Rejas
    No se pudo conectar estaciones
    LR Las Rejas
    EC Ecuador
    No se pudo conectar estaciones
    EC Ecuador
    AH San Alberto Hurtado
    No se pudo conectar estaciones
    Violación de segmento
```

La información de la lista:

```
    SP San Pablo
    NP Neptuno
    PJ Pajaritos
    LR Las Rejas
    EC Ecuador
    AH San Alberto Hurtado
    US Universidad de Santiago
    EL Estación Central
    LA ULA
    RP República
    LH Los Héroes
    LM La Moneda
    CH Universidad de Chile
    SL Santa Lucía
    UC Universidad Católica
    BA Baquedano
    SA Salvador
    MM Manuel Montt
    PV Pedro de Valdivia
    LE Los Leones
    TB Tobalaba
    GO El Golf
    AL Alcántara
    EM Escuela Militar
    MQ Manquehue
    HM Hernando de Magallanes
    LD Los Dominicos
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es dificil de entender porque falta más de la mitad del código. En el programa tienes varias funciones que manipulan y gestionan la lista y sus nodos y solo has puesto dos de ellas.

Aun así ya te puedo adelantar que una lista no es un nodo, de la misma moneda que una rueda no es un coche. Para no repetir, puedes ver más información al respecto en esta otra [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/169454/463).

Por otro lado, no veo motivo que justifique pasar de `std::string` a `char*`. La clase `std::string` nació precisamente para evitar los malos vicios de `char*`, tipo de dato donde es tremendamente sencillo meter la pata, y para muestra un botón:

```
bool comparacion_estaciones(string estacion1, string estacion2 ){ 
  char modificar1[5], modificar2[4];
  char *token1, *token2;

  strcpy(modificar1,estacion1.c_str());strcpy(modificar2,estacion2.c_str()); 
  token1 = strtok(modificar1," ");token2 = strtok(modificar2," ");

  if(*token1 == *token2) {
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

¿Por qué `modificar1` y `modificar2` tienen tamaños distintos? Tenemos que tener en cuenta esto a la hora de decidir qué estación ponemos la primera y cual la segunda? Si desbordamos cualquiera de los dos arrays el programa podría empezar a comportarse de forma errática...

Y por si esto no fuera poco, resulta que la función desborda **siempre**. ¿Cómo lo se si no puedo probar el código? Por los ejemplos que has puesto:

SP San Pablo
   NP Neptuno
   PJ Pajaritos

En base al código entiendo que `estacion1` y `estacion2` almacenan una línea completa del ejemplo anterior, es decir, almacenarán unos 10-15 caracteres... y resulta que copias ese chorizo en un array con capacidad para 4 caracteres (caso de `modificar1`) y para 3 caracteres (`modificar2`).

Con lo sencillo que es copiar un `std::string` en otro y, además, así te quitas de problemas:

```
bool comparacion_estaciones(string estacion1, string estacion2 ){ 
  std::string modificar1 = estacion1;
  std::string modificar2 = estacion2;

  char *token1 = strtok(modificar1.c_str()," ");
  char *token2 = strtok(modificar2.c_str()," ");
```

Además, piensa que los `char*` no se pueden comparar así como así. La línea

```
if(*token1 == *token2) {
```

No comprueba que el contenido de ambas cadenas sea idéntico... sino que comprueba si ambos punteros almacenan la misma dirección de memoria... teniendo en cuenta que las cadenas las estás copiando en `modificar1` y `modificar2` veo dificil que ambos punteros acaben direccionando la misma posición de memoria.

`std::string` posee una característica bastante versátil... iteradores. Los iteradores son objetos que nos permiten iterar (qué nombres mas curiosos usan en C++) los elementos que componen el objeto principal. En este caso con los iteradores podemos movernos a través de la cadena de caracteres. La ventaja de los iteradores es que se pueden hacer multitud de operaciones con ellos.

Así, por ejemplo, lo que a ti te interesa es el código de la estación, que casualmente ocupa siempre los dos primeros caracteres de la cadena. Puedes entonces quedarte con ese rango y construir una nueva cadena a partir de el:

```
std::string modificar1(estacion1.begin(),estacion1.begin()+2);
std::string modificar2(estacion2.begin(),estacion2.begin()+2);
```

O, si prefieres usar la STL en todo su esplendor:

```
std::string modificar1(estacion1.begin(),std::next(estacion1.begin(),2));
std::string modificar2(estacion2.begin(),std::next(estacion2.begin(),2));
```

Y ya está, ahora en `modificar1` y `modificar2` se almacena única y exclusivamente el código de la estación. Y como además estas variables son de tipo `std::string`, podemos usar el operador de comparación directamente:

```
if( modificar1 == modificar2 )
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

Claro que esta comparación se puede simplificar muchísimo:

```
return (modificar1 == modificar2);
```