# Error al ordenar por inserción en una lista

Tags: c++

Estoy realizando un pequeño programa que se basa en una encuesta en donde se pide una serie de datos para conformar así un registro de cada encuestado, quisiera poder ordenar estos datos en orden alfabético de los productos que se pueden apreciar en el código ademas me exigen utilizar el método de ordenamiento llamado inserción pero no se como hacer que ordene por lista ya que al inicio de este programa lo realice con una estructura simple y vectores en donde me ordenaba todo correctamente pero ahora me exigen usar lista y de verdad no se como hacerlo, solo pude hacer que se muestre los datos pero no me lo ordena.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
struct datos_encuesta{
char P[20], EST[20], E[20], SX[20], D[20];
int C;
};

typedef datos_encuesta datos;

struct nodo{
datos de;
struct nodo *sgte;
struct nodo *ante;
};

typedef struct nodo *lista;
lista inicio, fin;
//SE DECIDIO ORDENAR EN ORDEN ALFABETICO QUEDANDO DE LA SIGUIENTE MANERA

#define LD 2
#define LE 3
#define YG 4
#define HE 1


int n, aux, i, j,ld,le,yg,he;
char aux1[20],aux2[20],aux3[20],aux4[20],aux5[20];

void menu (){
cout<<"\t\t\tSELECCIONE LA OPCION DESEADA\n\n"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t1-INCLUIR DATOS\n"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t2-GENERAR REPORTE\n"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t3-CONSULTAR LOS DATOS RECOLECCTADOS\n"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t4-MODIFICAR LOS DATOS RECOLECCTADOS\n"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t5-ELIMINAR DATOS\n"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t6-SALIR"<<endl;
Sleep(1000);
}
//En esta función se ingresa todos los datos del encuestado
void incluir (){
int opc;
lista nuevo=new nodo();
    cout<<"\t\tESCOJA EL PRODUCTO DE SU PREFERENCIA:"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t1- LECHE DESCREMADA"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t2- LECHE ENTERA"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t3- YOGURT"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t4- HELADO"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t5- REGRESAR\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\t\t"; cin>>opc;
    switch(opc){
        case 1:{
            strcpy(nuevo->de.P,"LD");   
            nuevo->de.C=LD;
            strcpy(nuevo->de.D,"LECHE DESCREMADA");
            ld++;
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            strcpy(nuevo->de.P,"LE");
            nuevo->de.C=LE;
            strcpy(nuevo->de.D,"LECHE ENTERA");
            le++;
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            strcpy(nuevo->de.P,"YG");
            nuevo->de.C=YG;
            strcpy(nuevo->de.D,"YOGURT");
            yg++;
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            strcpy(nuevo->de.P,"HE");
            nuevo->de.C=HE;
            strcpy(nuevo->de.D,"HELADO");
            he++;
            break;
        }
        case 5:{

cout<<"\n\t\tREGRESANDO";
Sleep(500);
cout<<".";
Sleep(500);
cout<<".";
Sleep(500);
cout<<".";
            system("cls");
            return;
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout<<"\n\t\tOPCION NO DISPONIBLE"<<endl;
            Sleep(800);
            system("cls");
            break;
    }
    system("cls");
    Sleep(200);
    cout<<"\t\tESCOJA EL ESTRATO SOCIO-ECONOMICO AL QUE PERTENECE:"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t1- CLASE ALTA Y MEDIA ALTA"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t2- CLASE MEDIA TiPICA"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t3- CLASE MEDIA BAJA"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t4- CANCELAR INGRESO DE DATOS\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\t\t"; cin>>opc;
    switch(opc){
        case 1:{
            strcpy(nuevo->de.EST,"CLA");
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            strcpy(nuevo->de.EST,"CLB");
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            strcpy(nuevo->de.EST,"CLC");
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            delete(nuevo);
            return;
            break;
        }
        default:{
            cout<<"\n\t\tOPCION NO DISPONIBLE"<<endl;
            Sleep(1000);
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
    }
    system("cls");
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\t\tESPECIFIQUE SU EDAD ENTRE LOS SIGUIENTES RANGOS:"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t1- JOVEN"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t2- ADULTO"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t3- ADULTO MAYOR"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t4- CANCELAR INGRESO DE DATOS\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\t\t"; cin>>opc;
    switch(opc){
        case 1:{
            strcpy(nuevo->de.E,"EJ");
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            strcpy(nuevo->de.E,"AD");
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            strcpy(nuevo->de.E,"ADM");
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            delete(nuevo);
            return;
            break;
        }
        default:{
            cout<<"\n\t\tOPCION NO DISPONIBLE"<<endl;
            Sleep(1000);
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n"; Sleep(500);
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\t\tESPECIFIQUE SU SEXO:"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t1- HOMBRE"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t2- MUJER"<<endl;
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<"\n\t\t3- CANCELAR INGRESO DE DATOS\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\t\t"; cin>>opc;
    switch(opc){
        case 1:{
            strcpy(nuevo->de.SX,"M");
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            strcpy(nuevo->de.SX,"F");
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            delete(nuevo);
            return;
            break;
        }
        default:{
            cout<<"\n\t\tOPCION NO DISPONIBLE"<<endl;
            Sleep(1000);
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
    }
    cout<<"\t\tGUARDANDO";
Sleep(800);
cout<<".";
Sleep(800);
cout<<".";
Sleep(800);
cout<<".";
    if(inicio==NULL){
        inicio=nuevo;
        inicio->sgte=NULL;
        fin=inicio;
    }
    else{
        fin->sgte=nuevo;
        nuevo->sgte=NULL;
        nuevo->ante=fin;
        fin=nuevo;
    }
    system("cls");
Sleep(1500);
}
//En esta función debería mostrar los datos y a su vez ir organizando 
void mostrar(){
cout<<"\t\tORGANIZANDO";
Sleep(800);
cout<<".";
Sleep(800);
cout<<".";
Sleep(800);
cout<<".";
lista actual= new nodo();
lista previo= new nodo();
actual=inicio;
//Esta como comentario porque el programa se traba 
    /*while(inicio->sgte!=NULL){
    actual=actual->sgte;    //j
    previo=actual->ante;    //j-1
    aux = actual->de.C;
    strcpy(aux1,actual->de.SX);
    strcpy(aux2,actual->de.E);
    strcpy(aux3,actual->de.EST);
    strcpy(aux4,actual->de.D);
    strcpy(aux5,actual->de.P);
    while(previo!=NULL && aux<previo->de.C){
        actual->de.C = previo->de.C;
        inicio->de.C=aux;

        strcpy(actual->de.SX,previo->de.SX);
        strcpy(inicio->de.SX,aux1);

        strcpy(actual->de.E,previo->de.E);
        strcpy(inicio->de.E,aux2);

        strcpy(actual->de.EST,previo->de.EST);
        strcpy(inicio->de.EST,aux3);

        strcpy(actual->de.D,previo->de.D);
        strcpy(inicio->de.D,aux4);

        strcpy(actual->de.P,previo->de.P);
        strcpy(inicio->de.P,aux5);
        actual=actual->sgte;
        previo=actual->ante;
    }
}*/
system("pause");
system("cls");
while(actual!=NULL){
        cout<<"\n\t\tENCUESTADO ";
        cout<<"\n\t\tSEXO:"<<actual->de.SX;
        cout<<"\n\t\tEDAD:"<<actual->de.E;
        cout<<"\n\t\tESTRATO SOCIO-ECONOMICO:"<<actual->de.EST;
        cout<<"\n\t\tDESCRIPCION DEL PRODUCTO:"<<actual->de.D<<"("<<actual- >de.P<<")";
        cout<<"\n\t\tCODIGO DEL PRODUCTO:"<<actual->de.C<<endl;;
        cout<<"\n\t\t";
        actual=actual->sgte;
}
}

int main(){
system("color 0A");
int op;
inicio=NULL;
fin=NULL;
do{
menu(); cout<<"\n\t\t"; cin>>op;
switch(op){
    case 1:{
        system("cls");
        incluir();
        break;
    }
    case 2:{
        system("cls");
        mostrar();
        break;
    }
    case 3:{
        break;
    }
    case 4:{
        break;
    }
    case 5:{
        break;
    }
    case 6:{
        break;
    }
    default:
        cout<<"OPCION NO DISPONIBLE"<<endl;
        Sleep(1000);
        system("cls");
        break;
}
}while(op>=1&&op<=5);
cout<<"\n\t\tHASTA PRONTO..."; Sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Un nodo no es una lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/169454/463). Esto es algo que ya se ha dicho unas cuantas veces en SOes. Es un tema recurrente.

Por otro lado no entiendo que necesidad hay de complicar el lenguaje con alias sin sentido:

```
typedef struct nodo *lista;
```

Este alias ya te obliga a recordar que `lista` es **siempre** un puntero. C++ ya es lo suficientemente complicado como para que le echemos más leña. Mi experiencia tanto personal como en [es.so] es que los punteros deben ser visibles **siempre**. Si los ocultas bajo un alias y ese alias no da ideas de que se trata de un puntero, tu código va a darte problemas.

En cualquier caos basta mirar las primeras líneas del código para ver que algo no va bien:

```
lista actual= new nodo();
lista previo= new nodo();
actual=inicio;                              // (1)
//Esta como comentario porque el programa se traba 
    /*while(inicio->sgte!=NULL){            // (2)
    actual=actual->sgte;    //j
    previo=actual->ante;    //j-1           // (1) (3)
```

1. Dos líneas antes has creado un objeto nuevo en `actual`... esta asignación hace que pierdas la memoria de dicha reserva (tu programa tiene fugas de memoria). Nota que pasa exactamente lo mismo en el caso de `previo`.
2. Si estás usando `actual`... ¿Por qué aquí cambias a `inicio`? Esta línea puede provocar bucles sin fín
3. ¿Qué pasa si en la línea anterior, `actual->sgte == NULL`? spoiler: esta línea intentará hacer `previo=NULL->ante`. Este caso se debería solucionar si arreglas el caso 1.

Aparte de lo comentado, no entiendo que esta pregunta se etiquete como c++ cuando, salvo por `new`, `cin` y `cout`, todo lo demás es compatible con C. Si no es un requisito:

- Sustituye los `char*` por `std::string`.
- Los `Sleep` sobran. Si te mola simular retardos, dejalos para el final. No te imaginas la cantidad de tiempo que te vas a desperdiciar durante la fase de pruebas.
- En C++ no hace falta usar `struct nodo` todo el rato. El siguiente código es legal en C++:

  ```
  struct nodo{
    datos de;
    nodo *sgte; // sin struct
    nodo *ante; // sin struct
  };
  ```
- No uses variables globales. Te van a dar más problemas que alegrías. Aun no estás haciendo nada lo suficientemente complejo que justifique el uso de variables globales.
- Evita el uso de `#define`. Esta directiva evita que puedas beneficiarte del tipado fuerte de C++. Es preferible usar `const` o, a partir de C++11, `constexpr`:

  ```
  // NO
  #define LD 2

  // SI
  const int LD = 2;

  // SI (C++11 en adelante)
  constexpr int LD = 2;
  ```
- Usa nombres adecuados para las variables y las constantes. `LD` no significa **absolutamente nada**.
- Tabula correctamente el código. La legibilidad es muy importante.