# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar un elemento de una lista en c++?

Tags: c++

Quisiera eliminar un elemento de una lista en el bool C++. Soy muy novato en el C++ pero quisiera saber cómo puede ser posible eliminar un elemento que yo agregue en una lista de compras. Les dejo el código y si necesitan más información se las daré.

```
#include "Lista.h"

Lista::Lista(): _primer(NULL) , _ultimo(NULL)
{

}

void Lista::Agregar(Elemento* elemento)
{

    if(_primer ==NULL){
            _primer = elemento;
            _ultimo = elemento;
        }

    else{


    }

}

bool Lista::Eliminar(int indice)
{




    return false;


}
```

Todo eso parte de varios archivos, aquí les dejo la clase en la que se basa esta clase.

```
#ifndef LISTA_H
#define LISTA_H

#include "Elemento.h"

class Lista
{
    public:
        Lista();
        void Agregar(Elemento* elemento);
        Elemento* GetPrimer() { return _primer; }
        bool Eliminar(int indice);

    private:
        Elemento* _primer;
        Elemento* _ultimo;

};
#endif
```

Si necesitan más datos con gusto se los daré, y muchas gracias por leer.

Clase Main.cpp

```
#include "Lista.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
Lista* lista = new Lista();


void Listar()
{
    cout << endl << endl;
    int i = 1;
    Elemento* e = lista->GetPrimer();
    while(e != NULL)
    {
        cout << i << "- " << e->GetNombre() << " " << e->GetCantidad() << endl;
        e = e->GetSiguiente();
        i++;
    }
    if(i == 1)
    {
        cout << endl << "** Lista vacÃ­a **" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void Introducir()
{
    string nombre;
    int cantidad;

    cout << "Introducir el nombre del artÃ­culo: ";
    cin >> nombre;
    cout << "Introduzca la cantidad del nuevo arti­culo: ";
    cin >> cantidad;
    Elemento* elemento = new Elemento(nombre, cantidad);
    lista->Agregar(elemento);
    cout << "-- Articulo Agregado. Presione ENTER para regresar al menu principal--" << endl;
    getline(cin, nombre);
    cout << endl;
}

void Eliminar()
{
    int indice = 0;
    Listar();
    cout << "Elija el articulo a eliminar => ";
    cin >> indice;
    lista->Eliminar(indice - 1);
    cout << endl;
    Listar();
    cout << endl;
}

void MostrarMenu()
{
    int opcion = 0;
    do
    {        
        cout << "1- Listar articulos" << endl;
        cout << "2- Introducir arti­culo" << endl;
        cout << "3- Eliminar Articulo" << endl;
        cout << "4- Salir" << endl;
        cout << "Elija una opcion=> ";
        cin >> opcion;

        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                Listar();
            break;
            case 2:
                Introducir();
            break;
            case 3:
                Eliminar();
            break;
            case 4:
                exit(0);
            break;
            default:
                cout << "opcion invalida" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }while(opcion != 4);
}

int main()
{
    MostrarMenu();
    return 0;
}
```

Esta es la clase Main. Eso se divide por varias clases pero creo que ya puse las clases más importantes donde se basa lo de eliminar.

Comment: ¿Estás desarrollando una lista para practicar o esta lista forma parte de un código mayor?

Comment: Forma parte de un codigo mayor. Lo demás como el menu se encuentra en una clase llamada main, la voy a postear.

Comment: Por lo que veo, estás preguntando sobre cuál es la implementación del borrado de una lista enlazada. ¿Podrías compartir lo que has hecho al momento sobre el borrado?

Comment: Lo estuve haciendo de varias formas, pero quiero ver si puedo hacerlo con if. Aquí te dejo lo que estuve haciendo:

bool Lista::Eliminar(int indice)
{

if(indice == 0){

    return true;


}







else{
 return false;
}

Si, se que es simple, pero siento que más o menos se puede hacer. El problema es que no borra nada al momento de ejecutarlo.

Comment: Te podemos ayudar con problemas que tengas pero ¿Qué sentido tendría que te hiciésemos la implementación?

Comment: No lo tendría, pero es que en serio quisiera saber eso. Me tiene perdido.

Comment: Entonces creo que [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/169454/2742) te será de utilidad.