# ¿Como haga para saber si dicha palabra en una lista enlazada simple apuntada por cab es palindrome?

Tags: c++

Es decir tengo una lista simple apuntada por cab1 y hago la replica en una lista apuntada por cab2. como haga para saber si la letra se lee igual de izquierda a derecha, que de derecha a izquierda.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
struct nodo
{
  char letra;
  nodo *sig;
};
int main() {
  int opc=1;
  nodo *cab,  *nuevo, *q, *cab2;
  cab=NULL;
    while(opc==1)
    {
        printf("\nSuministre una letra:");
        // protocolo para preparacion del nodo
        // se pide el dato      nuevo= new (nodo) ;      // se pide el nodo nuevo y se cuelga del puntero llamado nuevo
        nuevo= new (nodo) ;
        cin >> nuevo->letra ;     // se ingresa la informacion al nodo
        nuevo->sig=NULL;
        if( cab == NULL)
        {
            cab=nuevo;
            q=cab;
        }
        else
        {
            q->sig=nuevo;
      q=nuevo;
        }
        printf("\n Desea continuar ? (1:SI, 2: NO) ? :");
        cin >> opc;
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Podéis invertir la réplica de tu lista y después comparar los dos, la lista original y la réplica invertida.

Answer (score 1):

> Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

Lo que tienes hasta ahora es una jerigonza sin sentido:

1. Programas en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) pero usas la cabecera `<stdio.h>` que es de [c](/questions/tagged/c). No debes usarla, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/48305/2742).
2. Dices "*Tengo una lista simple*", pero no tienes ni una lista, ni simple. Lo que tienes es un objeto `nodo` que además usas mal, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/169453/2742).
3. Dices "*Apuntada por `cab1`*", pero esa variable ni siquiera existe en tu código.
4. Dices "*Hago la replica en una lista apuntada por `cab2`*", pero `cab2` es un nodo, no una lista y ni siquiera le das uso en tu código.
5. Dices "*¿Cómo haga para saber si la **letra** se lee igual de izquierda a derecha, que de derecha a izquierda?*", pero las letras ya cumplen con esa condición.
6. Usas `NULL` que no es más que una macro que se transforma en `0`, deberías estar usando el literal de puntero nulo `nullptr`.
7. Usas `printf` que es una función de las rutinas de C, dado que estás en C++ deberías usar `std::cout`.
8. No inicializas el `sig` del primer nodo que insertas.
9. No compartes el código que usas para visualizar los datos.
10. No compartes el código de limpieza de la memoria dinámica usada.

Es normal que no sepas qué hacer, ni siquiera sabes qué has hecho.

---

No hay ninguna manera sencilla de comprobar si una lista simplemente enlazada es un palíndromo, yo copiaría el contenido de la lista a una cadena y comprobaría si la cadena invertida es igual a la original:

```
struct lista
{
    void push(char letra)
    {
        top = top ? new nodo{letra, top} : new nodo{letra};
    }

    ~lista()
    {
        delete top;
    }

    struct nodo
    {
        char letra;
        nodo *sig = nullptr;
        ~nodo()
        {
            delete sig;
        }
    };

    nodo *top = nullptr;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const lista &l)
{
    for (auto top = l.top; top; top = top->sig)
        o << top->letra;
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    int opc = 1;
    lista l;

    while (opc == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "\nSuministre una letra:";
        char letra;
        std::cin >> letra;
        l.push(letra);

        std::cout << "\n Desea continuar ? (1:SI, 2: NO) ? :";
        std::cin >> opc;
    }

    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string original, invertido;
    ss << l;
    ss >> original;
    invertido = original;
    std::reverse(invertido.begin(), invertido.end());

    if (invertido == original)
        std::cout << invertido << " es palindromo de " << original;

    return 0;
}
```

Como puedes ver, he creado un objeto `lista` en el que he anidado el `nodo`, le ha añadido destructor para limpiar la memoria dinámica y le proporcioné una sobrecarga al operador de escritura en flujo de datos, lo que permite pasar su información a un flujo de texto que podemos invertir.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVM9b9swEJ3FX3FwgUAuHCPuKKnOkiVLO2TtwkqMTIA@CvxIhsD56@6dSFmqYwOUzffevTs@yu0w3LdGYn8@f9PYmtgpaLT1wSl53IsZ8zeg4DT2S0Sa3jodDiQTxMY2gNE@SPEhijerOxiiP5TtQTowKji5FgUxRbAD/AR@PgKqd0Db2Y9RsGH0BNUVfKpFcRKi@Bzdy2zTKSIVV2Q6j8B1STF3JkXBOHz3uqfmGI0ZgmP4k3H2HEsmV5IxeSLnmqxTbRr8UsuMD11V5fzgzg7KyWBd05RXxAZaiz7nA3dmzRm9WgeljMFCcjZbPgxMjxTS/Z5m4fEsNE0CpiM5FaJDsDSKEBoDHKXGcrTmnR1astiRMHU1fJL3gzYKypEjMmc5TtvaGLjH6g@@xKNGzdNDRJkyrFb1l0xTnUbY72fQbMd7T1dOPSF/vnSBJ@WV5GSCxki@j1DuqpfnDfyo4NfvNe3HppPBshsd4HLthKaXM8ftff0fDPSW9hql2YDGN@WC7iwrPM9h0i@2zKqa48syCnABj55OEedVedFs/6qec1@4bxV25ZoPX@hXKBd2s9/6OvdZxfGA8jBIo7Fz9miB/m8rxudpLvf/QPd/PkuxE0hL0wq0eG/yd0/L0nK0uhuczFzIOswY5n3I/FI/1XeZsze4kOdJfg/iHw)</kbd>.

Comment: Usas std::string y std::reverse para hacer todo el trabajo. ¿Por qué necesitas una lista vinculada?

Comment: ¿Por qué programar una lista teniendo `std::list`?

Comment: Qué pena que no deje votar más de una vez una respuesta....

Comment: No es necesario a menos que sea una tarea. Y si es una tarea, tu solución probablemente no será aceptada.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Si quien pregunta tiene restricciones a lo que necesita debería haberlas mencionado. En caso contrario, pasar a cadena e invertirla es tan válido como cualquier otra respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, si no que el profesor lo explica de esa manera la verdad es que soy nuevo en esto.