# listas enlazadas en c++

Tags: c++, array, estructuras-de-datos

Me dejaron un problema en la universidad y no le entiendo muy bien al docente:

> Utilizando como estructura una lista enlazada, escriba una función que cuente el número de veces que aparece un entero dado en una lista enlazada.
>
> Explicación, dada una lista enlazada individualmente y una clave, cuente el número de ocurrencias de la clave dada en la lista enlazada. Por ejemplo, si la lista enlazada dada es 1->2>1->2->1->3->1 y la clave dada es 1, entonces la salida debería ser 4.

Mi código es el siguiente

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
void printlist(node *siguiente){
    while(siguiente !=NULL){
        cout<<"->"<<siguiente->data;
        siguiente=siguiente->next;
    }
    
}
void elemento(node *siguiente){
    int n;
    cout<<"\ningrese la clave: \n";cin>>n;
    if(siguiente->data<2 || siguiente->data==1){
        cout<<"tiene 4 repeticiones";
    }else{
        if(siguiente->data==3 ||n==3){
            cout<<"tiene 1 repeticion";
        }else{
            if(siguiente->data==2 ||n==2){
                cout<<"tiene 2 repeticiones";
            }
        }
    }
}
    
int main()
{
    node * head = NULL;
    node * second= NULL;
    node * third= NULL;
    node * siguiente= NULL;
    node * f4=NULL;
    node * f5=NULL;
    node * f6=NULL;
    node * f7=NULL;
    
    head=new node();
    second=new node();
    third=new node();
    f4=new node();
    f5=new node();
    f6=new node();
    f7=new node();
    
    head->data = 1;
    head->next = second;
    
    second->data = 2;
    second->next = third;
    
    third->data = 1;
    third->next = f4;
    f4->data = 2;
    f4->next = f5;
    f5->data = 1;
    f5->next = f6;
    f6->data = 3;
    f6->next = f7;
    f7->data = 1;
    f7->next = NULL;
    
    printlist(head);
    elemento(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Lo hice a la forma as sencilla posible solo para ese caso, pero se que no resuelve el problema general quisiera su ayuda.

Comment: Tienes que decir cuántas veces aparece un número dado por el usuario en la lista enlazada. Para ello debes recorrer la lista (pasar por todos sus nodos) y contar cuántos nodos tienen el valor pedido

Comment: Estás usando C++ (o eso nos das a entender con las etiquetas), haz que `node` sea una clase e implementa funcionalidad en ella.

Answer (score 1):

En tu código estás presentando varias situaciones que se consideran mala práctica o [código hediondo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hediondez_del_c%C3%B3digo).

1. [No estás encapsulando los datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/169453/2742) ya que los nodos, (que no tiene sentido que sean accesibles) están disponibles en el código
2. No sigues el [principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica) ya que la función que busca elementos también los pide.
3. No liberas la memoria dinámica que estás pidiento.

Te aconsejo que resuelvas el primer problema creando un objeto lista que permita añadir datos:

```
struct list
{
    void add(int data)
    {
        if (root && head)
        {
            head->next = new node{data};
            head = head->next;
        }
        else
        {
            root = head = new node{data};
        }
    }

private:
    struct node
    {
        int data = 0;
        node *next{nullptr};
    };

    node *root{nullptr};
    node *head{nullptr};
};
```

Después puedes añadirle una función que cuente un dato:

```
int count(int data)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (node *n = root; n; n = n->next)
        result += n->data == data;

    return result;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZLbasMwDIav7acQHZRko2WHu6TNk/TGJGpncOXgON2g5NkzyUlod4BBA/Iv@dNvqXXbbmpn6DSOD5Zq1zcIO@u7GNCcK6056OsIznZRX7W6eNuAaZrMUoTGRJNrxbKyR8iC9xHWa3hH07CcdCWHTUX4GWEPhB9AvsGr3BzKJc@ZW5moA3/oOlwgiTwV/Unh@kFrJZ5q31P85Y6PAbveCeW55FJ19AEyocAjsSgdSiD@SYPJSZ5aT9eekipI2O8TOlECxj7QzC6TizbYi4lYaDWPTprcbEwIMaHU3J5bXal3ro1BXjMIeUqJq/vUpMoY7lSpF/LZWMpyWZIsC5xg3FZ29ZKXS/h6C/9V376rWl7UFAVPOMJuB6sDWTrx0xGcAf4PXbCAA63KeRNULhcsQVXJ@SchWiSElcRuO22O8pThkbYYbW09YZeQ86h5cMM4vugv)</kbd>. No olvides liberar la memoria.

Comment: muchas gracias por su ayuda, como se puede ver i codigo es muy ineficiente, lamentablemente el ingeniero encargado de enseñarnos ese curso no nos da una explicaicon completa y solo pude escribir un codigo asi