# Manejo de pilas en C++

Tags: c++, pilas

Al ejecutar el programa me sale el error **segmentation fault (core dumped)**. El programa recibe una expresión en notación polaca y retorna el resultado de la expresión (en teoría) y tengo este problema desde que implemente una función para borrar un nodo en específico, aquí dejo una muestra de la función principal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "nodo.h"
#include "lista.h"

using namespace std;

Lista CrearLista() {
    Lista * lista = new Lista();
    string expresion;
    string elemento;

    cout << "Ingrese una expresión en notación prefija: ";
    getline(cin, expresion);

    expresion += " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < expresion.length(); i++) {
        if (expresion[i] != ' ') {
            elemento += expresion[i];
        } else {
            Nodo * entrada = new Nodo(elemento);
            lista -> push(entrada);
            elemento = "";
        }
    }

    return * lista;
}

string calculadora(string op, Nodo n1, Nodo n2) {
    int num1 = stoi(n1.getElemento());
    int num2 = stoi(n2.getElemento());

    if (op == "+") {
        return to_string(num1 + num2);
    } else if (op == "-") {
        return to_string(num1 - num2);
    } else if (op == "*") {
        return to_string(num1 * num2);
    } else if (op == "/" && num2 != 0) {
        return to_string(num1 / num2);
    } else {
        cout << "operacion invalida" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

Lista traductor(Lista lista) {

    Nodo * elemento = lista.cabeza;
    string resultado;

    while (elemento != NULL) {
        Nodo * penultimo = elemento;
        Nodo * ultimo = elemento -> sig;

        if (ultimo -> sig -> esOperador()) {
            resultado = calculadora(ultimo -> sig -> getElemento(), * ultimo, * penultimo);

            lista.erase(ultimo -> sig -> getElemento());
            lista.erase(ultimo -> getElemento());
            lista.erase(penultimo -> getElemento());

            lista.push(new Nodo(resultado));

            traductor(lista);
        }

        elemento = elemento -> sig;
    }

    return lista;
}

int main() {
    Lista lista = CrearLista();
    Lista resultado = traductor(lista);
    cout << "El resultado de su operacion es ";
    resultado.verLista();
}
```

Debería funcionar pero al parecer la función traductor tiene un error, he probado cambiando el tipo de dato que retorna pero sigue sin funcionar y sale siempre el mismo error.

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo de la entrada que recibe y el resultado esperado. Mira cómo crear un [example].

Answer (score 1):

> Debería funcionar

No.

---

El motivo exacto por el que te falla el programa no lo puedo saber con el código que compartes (aunque sospecho qué puede estar pasando), pero sí puedo saber que tu código está haciendo ciertas cosas **muy mal**.

Tu función `CrearLista` está devolviendo un objeto `Lista` por copia; dejando de lado que esa práctica es más propia de [c](/questions/tagged/c) que de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), si no has redactado correctamente el constructor de copia de `Lista` tu código fallará (como probablemente está pasando) pues intentará liberar memoria que no le pertenece o que no ha sido solicitada dinámicamente (eso da lugar a [*violaciones de acceso*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso)).

Además del constructor de copia posiblemente ausente o mal redactado, tenemos el problema de la creación de una instancia en memoria dinámica que después devuelves por copia:

```
Lista CrearLista() {
    Lista * lista = new Lista(); // Crear memoria dinámica

    // … hacer cosas…

    return * lista; // Devolver contenido del puntero, el puntero se pierde.
}
```

El puntero `lista` que creas en la función se pierde al salir de la función así que estás generando [fugas de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria).

Debes rediseñar todo tu código para hacerte cargo de la memoria de manera adecuada, echa un vistazo a [este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/169454/2742) para inspirarte.